# Zip file as InputStream then separating each file inside it then converting it to image. In Java

Tags: java, zip, arrays, inputstream, pdfbox

I am getting a zip file as an `InputStream`. I am then separating each file inside it. Then I am passing the same `byte array` to a [pdfbox](https://code.google.com/p/do-pdf/) which internally uses `Apace pdf box 1.6.0` to convert it to image.

However when I pass the `byte array` to the `PDFDocumentReader` I get the following exception-

```
SEVERE: expected='endstream' actual='' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@44c2beb9
java.io.IOException: expected='endstream' actual='' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@44c2beb9
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSStream(BaseParser.java:439)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:530)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:172)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:862)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:829)
at org.dopdf.document.read.pdf.PDFDocumentReader.init(PDFDocumentReader.java:98)
```

To fetch each file from the zip I use the following code -

```
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(aZipFile); // aZipFile is byte array
    ZipEntry entry;
    ArrayList<String> nameOfIgnoredFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    byte data[] = null;
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            int dataSize = (int)entry.getSize();
            data = new byte[dataSize];
            zis.read(data);
            // i use data and pass it to the pdf box.
        } else {
            nameOfIgnoredFiles.add(entry.getName());
        }
```

The `data` byte array that I fetch above is then passed to like below -

```
PDFDocumentReader document = new PDFDocumentReader(data); // here i get the error
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you suggest a solution? I guess the fetching of the data byte array is an issue. How to do it the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that `zis.read(data)` fills the buffer. Check the API documentation. It isn't guaranteed to do that. You are also assuming that the size fits into an int, and that the item itself fits into memory. None of these assumptions is valid.

Surely you can pass the entry's `InputStream` to a `pdfbox` API?

Comment: @Juniad (a) read in a loop until you get all the data you are expecting, which seems entirely obvious to me, or (b) use `DataInputStream.readFully()`, or (c) the considerably better suggestion contained in my final sentence above.

Comment: 1. I tried to read it in a loop however i faced a few issues in combining the byte arrays. 2. `DataInputStream` needs a `InputStream` in its constructor. Which one to pass? 3. Can pass `InputStream` however as I am saving the files in `HBase` I have to convert it into `byte array` so doing it before.

Comment: @Juniad (a) `zis` of course; (b) if it won't take an `InputStream`, copy `zis` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and get the bytes out of that.

Comment: I can pass zis to `DataInputStream` but how do can I separate the files which are zipped in the zip file that I receiving as a stream.

Comment: @Juniad you will get EOF when reading the input stream at the end of every item. Then advance to the next item and read again. When there are no more items, stop. This is all there in the Javadoc.

Comment: I am reading the `ZipInputStream` and then getting each `ZipEntry` which I am reading in chunks in a loop and writing it in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for every entry. Thanks for your hints and help.